# Restler3 Integration with Grafana SimpleJson plugin

Tags: restler

I'm trying to make an integration with Grafana, using Simple-Json databse plugin.

I configured the integration but needed some help on the Restler part.
I created a class (Compliance) in an instance of Restler that will fetch information from a database. I am accessing this class through the url http://ws.server.com.br/service/inventory/index.php/compliance
This is working fine, however the SimpleJson plugin needs to implement the following endpoints to work:

```
/
/search
/query
/annotations
```

The endpoint / is returning correctly, however I am having problems with the other endpoints.
Debugging the requests that are made in the webserver, I see that grafana is trying to make a post in the url http://ws.server.com.br/service/inventory/index.php/compliance/search, but error 405 occurs (method not allowed).
I know I need to implement a function post in this URL, but if I create this function in my class Compliance it is referring to the class itself, not the search method.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

405 means the URL is available but not for the specific method that is used which I assume is `POST` in this case, I guess your class us `Compliance` and method name is `search`. If you add a method named `postSearch` it will receive the grafana request

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later.